# How do I move a file from downloads to another directory using anaconda prompt in Windows 10?

Tags: anaconda

I'm typing the following command, but getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect":

```
move archive(1).zip C:\Users\owner\Documents\Online Classes\Udacity\Data Analyst Nanodegree\Data Wrangling\Datasets\
```

I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Windows file paths containing spaces must be enclosed in quotes.  That is a general computer usage question, not a programming or software development question applicable to Stack Overflow.  `move archive(1).zip "C:\Users\owner\Documents\Online Classes\Udacity\Data Analyst Nanodegree\Data Wrangling\Datasets\"`

Comment: Thank you. How is this not a programming question if I need to know how to do it programmatically to move tons of files at once?

Comment: Typing commands at a command prompt is not programming.  You never mentioned doing it programatically.  I withdrew my close vote; but you should change the question (remove the reference to the command prompt or "typing" commands)

Comment: ... and also the spaces in file paths needing enclosing quotes is a [general operating system issue](https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/) not  specific to programming.  Here space is a command  parameter delimiter, so that spaces in the path made it look like you were passing multiple parameters rather than a single path.

Comment: Thank you. I will be mindful to use the proper terminology in future questions.